# How can I have two models relate to one generic model?

Tags: django

Model "A" is a generic model, meaning any model can relate to it. Model "B" and "C" are models that want to establish a foreign key relation with Model "A". How can this be done?

```
class A(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    list = # What goes here?

class B(models.Model):
    parent = # What goes here to refer to model A?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class C(models.Model):
    parent = # What goes here to refer to model A?
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
```

An example lookup would be:

```
A.list.all()
```

Giving me a list of either B objects or C objects.

Comment: The reverse of a GenericForeignKey is a GenericRelation, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations). But there's no method that will give you a list of B and C objects given A.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know that. I know how I can relate model A in other models, but model A still needs to have a list of either B or C. To set it in a more real life example: Think of a Media model that can have several Images of different sizes, or it can have several Audio of different bitrates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use different related names which works in my case:

```
class A(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class B(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('A', related_name='B')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class C(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('A', related_name='C')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely the wrong design for what you are asking for. Your structure only allows one single item to be related to each A, whether it is a B or a C.

Instead you need an intermediate model, which contains the GenericForeignKey and which also has a (normal) ForeignKey to A. That is how tagging applications work: see for example django-tagging's [TaggedItem model](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-tagging/blob/develop/tagging/models.py#L494).